# Opencart SQL See which Product Have Options

Tags: mysql, opencart, product

I would like to know how to lookup which products have options and take a export so i can lookup the products on my site and change the prices for the products with options  and correct them.

Comment: Do you want this in the admin section?

Comment: That would be great. However i just really want a print out of all the product that have option enabled so i can change the prices. Not really sure how everybody handles this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's old but incase it helps anyone, this mysql query should return all the products that have options...

```
select * from product where product_id in (select product_id from product_option group by product_id) order by product_id
```